# Calling the calc stack from babel: displaying percentages

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, calc

Calc supports displaying results as percentages with `c %`. How can I make babel return this?  I tried:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC calc
1
2
'/
'c%
#+END_SRC
```

But this just gives an error. I also tried with a space separating `c` and `%` as well several other variations. How can I input this command? These kinds of commands are fairly common in calc, so surely there is a way to input them from babel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I input this command?

I believe you cannot.

I am convinced that this is a bug in `org-babel-execute:calc`: see [ob-calc.el, line 67](http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/tree/lisp/ob-calc.el?id=fdd9b18598239dd0e8b18383ac930110d51ed22e#n67).

`org-babel-execute:calc` expects every Calc "stack operation" to be a function taking a prefix argument which specifies the number of times it is applied. `calc-divide`, for example, takes a prefix argument, so line 3 of the script in the question works fine. The "`c%`" command corresponds to `calc-convert-percent`, which takes no arguments, and this results in a  "Wrong number of arguments" error (it is called as `(calc-convert-percent nil)`.)

Consider submitting a bug report.

**Update (November 6, 2014)**

An answer stating that this is a bug is not complete unless it contains a bug fix. :-)

There are *two* problems here:

1. As stated above, `org-babel-execute:calc` expects stack operations to take one argument.
2. Some Calc operations (`c%` is one of them) *do not* change the value but change the way it is printed. So, even after fixing the bug evaluating the source code block given in the question produces `0.5`, **not** `50%`.

I extended `org-babel-execute:calc` (see code below) so that

```
# this is equivalent to using ":results value"
#+BEGIN_SRC calc
1
2
'/
'c%
#+END_SRC
```

gives

```
#+RESULTS:
: 0.5
```

and

```
#+BEGIN_SRC calc :results output
1
2
'/
'c%
#+END_SRC
```

gives

```
#+RESULTS:
: 50%
```

(The reasoning is that `c%` changes the *output* of Calc.)

Here's the code:

```
(defun org-babel-execute:calc (body params)
  "Execute a block of calc code with Babel."
  (unless (get-buffer "*Calculator*")
    (save-window-excursion (calc) (calc-quit)))
  (let* ((vars (mapcar #'cdr (org-babel-get-header params :var)))
         (org--var-syms (mapcar #'car vars))
         (var-names (mapcar #'symbol-name org--var-syms)))
    (mapc
     (lambda (pair)
       (calc-push-list (list (cdr pair)))
       (calc-store-into (car pair)))
     vars)
    (mapc
     (lambda (line)
       (when (> (length line) 0)
         (cond
          ;; simple variable name
          ((member line var-names) (calc-recall (intern line)))
          ;; stack operation
          ((string= "'" (substring line 0 1))
           (let ((f (lookup-key calc-mode-map (substring line 1))))
             (condition-case nil
                 (funcall f nil)        ;; try calling with one arg
               (error (funcall f)))))   ;; if failed, call without args
          ;; complex expression
          (t
           (calc-push-list
            (list (let ((res (calc-eval line)))
                    (cond
                     ((numberp res) res)
                     ((math-read-number res) (math-read-number res))
                     ((listp res) (error "Calc error \"%s\" on input \"%s\""
                                         (cadr res) line))
                     (t (replace-regexp-in-string
                         "'" ""
                         (calc-eval
                          (math-evaluate-expr
                           ;; resolve user variables, calc built in
                           ;; variables are handled automatically
                           ;; upstream by calc
                           (mapcar #'org-babel-calc-maybe-resolve-var
                                   ;; parse line into calc objects
                                   (car (math-read-exprs line)))))))))
                  ))))))
     (mapcar #'org-babel-trim
             (split-string (org-babel-expand-body:calc body params) "[\n\r]"))))
  (save-excursion
    (with-current-buffer (get-buffer "*Calculator*")
      (if (equal (cdr (assoc :result-type params)) 'output)
          (math-format-value (calc-top 1)) ; return formatted value if asked for the output
        (calc-eval (calc-top 1))))))
```